# NPE on autowiring from dependent Project

Tags: spring, maven

This is my project structure,

Parent Projectt -->
                pom.xml
                  (sub modules core,web,services)

```
            core prj -->
                pom.xml
            web prj --> has core,services dependency and has ComponentScan for com.aaa.bbb
                pom.xml

            services prj --> has core, web dependency
                pom.xml
```

client Project -->
        pom.xml (sub modules xxx,yyy)

```
    xxx --> 
        pom.xml

    yyy --> has core dependency 
        pom.xml
```

xxx and yyy jars are used in core project and war is built by web project.

when i autowire services/repositories in yyy project i am getting NPE for services/repositories.

Can any one please let me know how i can autowire services/repositories in yyy project from core project services/repositories?

Thank you,

Comment: I have a question before I vote for close. `xxx and yyy jars are used in core`. What does that mean? Are xxx and yyy direct maven dependencies to core?  The existence of the parent depends on the existence of the child?

Comment: xxx and yyy are maven projects but not direct maven projects under core.for  rendering ui these jars are used in core.  xxx is parent to child yyy.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to autowire the bean from library, you have two options:

1. If you have access to the library code (I think this is your case):

   1.1 Add annotation to mark which class is bean (using `@Component`, `@Service`,...)

   1.2 In your configuration class (class which have `@Configuration` or `@SpringBootApplication` or `@ComponentScan`...), add path of `xxx` and `yyy` project to the classpath

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan("com.my.package.xxx,com.my.package.yyy")
   public class YourApplication
   ```
2. If you don't have access to the library code

   2.1 In your configuration class, create a `@Bean` annotated method and initialize your bean here.

   ```
   @Bean
   public XRepository getXRepository() {
    return new XRepositoryImpl(); // Here is your initialization logic
   }
   ```

Comment: 1.could you please elaborate more on this "add path of xxx and yyy project to the classpath" ?    2.I am using spring data jpa so here i have interface how i can initialize?

Comment: Add your package to scan classpath. See my edited answer

Comment: I have tired option 1 .. Still i am getting NPE. i am unable to figure out the problem.